# Type script visual studio code autocomplete

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I have converted a project from javascript to TypeScript but I do not see the autocomplete suggestion / types when I hover my mouse in Visual Studio Code editor (Version 1.7.2). Even the simple example below does not suggest auto complete or types of variables. Do we need to make any configurations in VS Code editor for this ? (or install any plugins), please suggest.

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName, public middleInitial, public lastName) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");
```

Comment: any reason why not using the latest version (i.e. 1.8.1)?

Comment: Its the same with v 1.8.1 as well.

Comment: what's the file extension? .ts?

Comment: @peval27 Yes it is .ts (TypeScript language mode in editor)

Comment: I think there's something wrong on your PC. Maybe try to reboot or also uninstall/reinstall. I have installed Visual Studio Code  on a clean VM, copy and pasted your code, save .ts and works.

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue with typescirpt sdk path - configured correct path in user settings typescript.tsdk and it works now.